# Get svg elements specific to a group using selectAll

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code.

On click of a button it adds a circle , on hovering the circle a red square is shown and on `mouseout` it will be hidden. For one circle it works perfectly. But since i'm using `d3.selectAll` , when there are multiple circle it shows and hides all red rectangles when hovered on one circle.

Is there a way to select the rectangle associated to circle that is hovered using the `d3.select` or `d3.selectAll` ?

*For demonstrating the problem in the code i've added 3 circles can be properly added*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = 560,
    height = 500;
  var i = -1;
  valArray = [100, 200, 300, 400];
  var svg = d3.select('#canvas')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  $("#add").click(function() {
    i++;


    var g = svg.append('svg:g')
      .attr('x', valArray[i])
      .attr('y', valArray[i]);

    var yesDecision = g.append('svg:rect')
      .style('fill', "#D64541")
      .attr("width", "50")
      .attr("height", "50")
      .attr("id", "yesDecision")
      .attr("class", "hoverNode")
      .attr("x", valArray[i])
      .attr("y", valArray[i]);

    g.append('svg:text')
      .attr('x', valArray[i])
      .attr('y', valArray[i])
      .attr('class', 'id hoverNode')
      .text(function(d) {
        return "Yes";
      });

    g.append('svg:circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 40)
      .attr('cx', valArray[i])
      .attr('cy', valArray[i])
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return ("#ccc");
      }).on('mouseover', function(d) {
        d3.selectAll(".hoverNode").style("visibility", "visible")
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        d3.selectAll(".hoverNode").style("visibility", "hidden")
      })

  });
});
```

```css
.hoverNode {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add element</button>
<div id="canvas">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is setting a specific class for each rectangle, based on `i`:

```
var yesDecision = g.append('rect')
    .attr("class", "hoverNode" + i)
```

And do the same for the circles:

```
g.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node' + i)
```

Then, inside your mouseover and mousemove, you select the rectangle based on the circle class:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    var elementID = d3.select(this).attr("class").slice(-1);
    d3.selectAll(".hoverNode" + elementID).style("visibility", "visible")
})
.on('mouseout', function(d) {
    var elementID = d3.select(this).attr("class").slice(-1);
    d3.selectAll(".hoverNode" + elementID).style("visibility", "hidden")
})
```

Here is the working code (click "run code snippet"):

```js
var width = 560,
    height = 500;
  var i = -1;
  valArray = [50, 120, 190, 260];
  var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  d3.select("#add").on("click", function() {
    i++;

    var g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('x', valArray[i])
      .attr('y', valArray[i]);

    var yesDecision = g.append('rect')
      .style('fill', "#D64541")
      .attr("width", "50")
      .attr("height", "50")
      .attr("id", "yesDecision")
   .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .attr("class", "hoverNode" + i)
      .attr("x", valArray[i])
      .attr("y", valArray[i]);

    g.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node' + i)
      .attr('r', 40)
      .attr('cx', valArray[i])
      .attr('cy', valArray[i])
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return ("#ccc");
      }).on('mouseover', function(d) {
   var elementID = d3.select(this).attr("class").slice(-1);
        d3.selectAll(".hoverNode" + elementID).style("visibility", "visible")
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d) {
   var elementID = d3.select(this).attr("class").slice(-1);
        d3.selectAll(".hoverNode" + elementID).style("visibility", "hidden")
      })
    
      g.append('text')
      .attr("x", valArray[i])
      .attr("y", valArray[i])
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .attr("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr('class', 'id hoverNode' + i)
      .text("Yes");

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: This is just a general example that you have to change to fit your needs. For instance, using `slice(-1)`, the example can only deal with 10 classes maximum.

Comment: Is there a way not to hide it when the mouse is moved to the element which was just shown ?

Comment: In the above case it is hidden when i try to hover over the newly shown element.

Comment: But that was what you asked: "and on mouseout it will be hidden". So, if you set the mouseout to the circle element, every time the mouse leaves the circle the rectangle disappears.

Comment: Yes that is what the question says. Anyway now i moved the mouse out onto new element and its working as i wanted. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to keep the rectangle visible when you move the mouse over it, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/4u0szt9m/

Answer (score 1):

You could bind rect as data to circle and then get access to rect in mouse events:

```
g.append('svg:circle')
      .data([yesDecision])
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 40)
      .attr('cx', valArray[i])
      .attr('cy', valArray[i])
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return ("#ccc");
      }).on('mouseover', function(d) {
        d.style("visibility", "visible")
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        d.style("visibility", "hidden")
      })
```

Here is your edited code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = 560,
    height = 500;
  var i = -1;
  valArray = [100, 200, 300, 400];
  var svg = d3.select('#canvas')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  $("#add").click(function() {
    i++;


    var g = svg.append('svg:g')
      .attr('x', valArray[i])
      .attr('y', valArray[i]);

    var yesDecision = g.append('svg:rect')
      .style('fill', "#D64541")
      .attr("width", "50")
      .attr("height", "50")
      .attr("id", "yesDecision")
      .attr("class", "hoverNode")
      .attr("x", valArray[i])
      .attr("y", valArray[i]);

    g.append('svg:text')
      .attr('x', valArray[i])
      .attr('y', valArray[i])
      .attr('class', 'id hoverNode')
      .text(function(d) {
        return "Yes";
      });

    g.append('svg:circle')
      .data([yesDecision])
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 40)
      .attr('cx', valArray[i])
      .attr('cy', valArray[i])
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return ("#ccc");
      }).on('mouseover', function(d) {
        d.style("visibility", "visible")
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        d.style("visibility", "hidden")
      })

  });
});
```

```css
.hoverNode {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add element</button>
<div id="canvas">
</div>
```